# Knockout JS select initial value is not displayed correctly inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a case when I have a list of items and for each item of them I need to display a dropdown list that edits a specific field

the case that happens is that when  I edit selection and save, the change is bound and saved correctly.

but when I load the page for the first time , all the selections reflect the very first item (the value is ignored)

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Model.Items">

    ///something

          <select data-bind="value: Fieldvalue,options: $root.optionslist,  optionsValue: 'Id', optionsText: 'Name'"></select>

    ///something

  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I am setting initial values and then the DOM is loaded and the values are bound. It is working as expected. Your problem might be in some other part of the code that you haven't shown us.

```js
var viewmodel = function(){
  
  this.Model = {
    Items: [
      {Fieldvalue: ko.observable(2)},
      {Fieldvalue: ko.observable(3)}
    ]
  };
  this.optionslist = [
    {Id: 1, Name: 'option 1'},
    {Id: 2, Name: 'option 2'},
    {Id: 3, Name: 'option 3'}
  ];
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div data-bind="foreach: Model.Items">
    <select data-bind="value: Fieldvalue,
                       options: $root.optionslist,  
                       optionsValue: 'Id', 
                       optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the same code I posted above with a Model set the same way you set yours, and it worked then, but since I populate it from a Model I received via AJAX call , my model was  assigned using ko.viewmodel.fromModel, and probably the problem lies in this line